# Use the same instance from more class

Tags: cocoa, class, instance

I have a little problem, when I have to access to one class I create a new instance

```
Class *class = [[Class alloc] init];
```

the problem is that I don't want to create a new instance but use the current instance, I want only to communicate between two class...how can I pass a value without create a new instance?

Comment: Trying not to create objects is working against the object-oriented nature of Objective-C, and trying “to communicate between two class[es]” suggests that you don't fully grasp the nature and purpose of classes. This document will explain a lot of what you're missing: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Singleton class to create a shared object that can be accessed for the lifetime of the app, here's a simple (though not 100% foolproof) way to create one:

```
+ (id) sharedInstance {
    static Foo *__sharedInstance;
    if (nil == __sharedInstance) {
        __sharedInstance = [[Foo alloc] init];
    }
    return __sharedInstance;
}
```

More [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)

If you just want to perform specific operations, or get information from the class, you can use a class method by using "+" instead of "-" in the method name like so:

```
+ (void) doSomething {
    NSLog(@"This class is %@", self);
}
```

Then you can simply call [Class doSomething] to perform operations without having to create a new instance.

Comment: thank you very much! I have only another question, when I pass a variable, to another class like this case, how can I do a simple refresh of a label?

Comment: Depends on how your app is designed, but generally you have a user interface item that is updated by a "controller class" that sits between the UI and the data classes. So you could tell your class to update its value, then the controller would read the new value and pass it to a text field or whatever. Bindings is a more powerful way to do this automatically, but that will require some reading on your part.